# Why does Scala name monadic composition as "for comprehension"?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, scala, semantics, monad

Not sure if it's an appropriate question, but here it goes.

I know Haskell's do notation pretty well. And I realized that Scala's "for comprehension" really is just mostly the same as do notation in Haskell. Something I don't quite understand is why did the designers choose this name though? The words "for" and "yield" seem likely to confuse programmers who are used to, for example, Java's for loop and Ruby's yield.

Yet I don't think monadic composition has much in common with those things at all. Is there a particular reason to name this syntactic sugar with such words? Or is it just mostly because a lot of keywords have already been occupied in the language, so they had to use these keywords which are relatively free?

Comment: Perhaps they took the construct from Erlang or Python, where it operates on sequences, and only later said "you know, monadic operations can look a lot like sequences if you squint."

Comment: @kdgregory: they can look like a *lot* of things if you squint. Haskell makes them look like imperative code, Scala makes them look like loops, C# makes them look like SQL.

Comment: What I mean is: there's not necessarily one right way to squint, and actually, Haskell's interpretation is also just squinting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are creating a bit of a false dichotomy here.

Haskell has monad comprehensions built into the language. One reason for that is the use of monads for imperative-style I/O. Therefore, the designers of Haskell decided to make it look mostly like a code block in a generic C-style language, complete with curly braces, semicolons and even `return`. The assignments look a bit non-C, but left-arrow for assignment is typical imperative pseudo-code.

So, monad comprehensions in Haskell were designed to look like imperative sequential side-effecting code blocks in some generic C/pseudo-code like language, because that's an important use case for them. This even permeates the API design with the naming of the aforementioned `return` function. Note that the name of this function doesn't really make much sense if you use it outside of `do` notation.

C# has monad comprehensions built into the language. One reason for that is the use of monads for querying of datasets. Therefore, the designers of C# decided to make it look mostly like SQL or XQuery, complete with `FROM`, `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `GROUPBY`, `ORDERBY`, etc. The order looks a bit non-SQL (`FROM` before `SELECT`), but it's the same one as used by XQuery, actually.

So, monad comprehensions in C# were designed to look like SQL queries, because that's an important use case for them. This even permeates the API design with the naming of e.g. `Select` for the transformation function (instead of `map`), `SelectMany` (instead of `flatMap`), `Where` (instead of `select` / `filter`), etc. Note that the names of these operations don't really make much sense if you use them outside of a query comprehension, and in fact, can even be actively confusing (`Select` is what is usually called `map`, whereas what is usually called `select` is `Where`).

Scala has monad comprehensions built into the language. One reason for that is the use of monads for collection operations. Therefore, the designers of Scala decided to make it look mostly like a `for` loop in a generic C-style language. The assignments look a bit non-C, but left-arrow for assignment is typical imperative pseudo-code.

So, monad comprehensions in Scala were designed to look like imperative `for` loops in some generic C/pseudo-code like language, because that's an important use case for them.

Note that both in the case of C# and Scala, the comprehension syntax can actually do *more* and/or *less* than just perform the two monadic operations `join` and `bind` (or `map` and `flatMap`). In Scala, a `for` comprehension without `yield` translates into `foreach`, i.e. an imperative side-effecting iteration, which really doesn't have much to do with monads at all. A `yield` can have a guard (`yield foo if bar`), which translates into a call to a call to `withFilter`, i.e. filtering elements. C# can do the same with `Where`. C# can also do aggregation (`group by`) and sorting (`order by`).

They are actually more of a generalization and/or fusion of monad comprehensions and list comprehensions generalized to arbitrary collections and monads. Note that Haskell also has both, but they are *different* things, in C# and Scala, they are fused together.

Haskell has a lot of history, and has pioneered a lot of concepts. As is typical with pioneers, often the people who come after them, discover better, shorter, safer routes. Maybe if Haskell had been designed with hindsight instead of innovation, they also would have generalized list comprehensions to work with more collections, and would have fused monad comprehensions and generalized collection comprehensions together, who knows? I know that there are proposed variants and extensions to Haskell, which add Arrow Comprehensions, for example.

> The words "for" and "yield" seem likely to confuse programmers who are used to, for example, Java's for loop and Ruby's yield.

The first one is intentional. It is *supposed* to look like a `for` loop.

The second one is unfortunate. The word `yield` has two (actually related but not obviously so) meanings. One is the meaning used in concurrency, coroutines, fibres, threads, and for the `yield` keyword and the `Fibre#yield` method in Ruby, where it means that a piece of code yields control of execution to another piece of code. The other is the meaning of a computation yielding a result. That's the meaning that is used in Python generators, C# generators, and interestingly also in Ruby, in the `Enumerator::Yielder#yield` method, and is the interpretation that is meant for the `yield` keyword in Scala `for` comprehensions.

Comment: "In Scala, a for comprehension without yield translates into foreach, i.e. an imperative side-effecting iteration, which really doesn't have much to do with monads at all." You can see foreach as a specialization of sequence_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (), where t :: [] and m :: IO or some other monad that models side effects.

Comment: The page https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension states that list comprehension syntax in Haskell was initially available for all monads, and was only later restricted to list only? And it seems that list comprehension in Haskell can be totally rewritten in terms of `do` notations. So what's the difference between monad comprehensions and generalized collections comprehensions exactly though. I'm a bit confused here. I think maybe in languages other than Haskell, more/less can be done with generalized comprehensions. But in Haskell, how are they exactly *different* things?

Comment: My grounding in those concepts is still not very solid yet.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have much background on why Scala designers made that particular wording choice, but in F#, local "do notation" equivalent is called a "computation expression". The reasoning behind that word choice is one of PR and marketing rather than any concrete technical reason.

Haskell has a hard-earned reputation of being a language for academics, rocket scientists and other weirdos, and one of the things that perpetuates this notion is its community's insistence on using type-theory derived terms out in the open. This is also a form of marketing - you could say its a conscious choice that makes it appealing to certain kinds of people (functional programming hipsters) and off-putting to others (say, like enterprise adopters).

For F#, they went with "computation expressions" and "computation expression builders" instead of "do notation" and "monads" supposedly in an attempt to not scare away people who are likely to pick up the language (existing .NET programmers who don't have a functional programming background).

I would imagine the case is similar for Scala. By calling it "for comprehensions", they want to sell the feature to people who might know nothing of monads, but who are familiar with list comprehensions in languages like Ruby and Python.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if `do` and `return` in Haskell are very much type-theory related terms. I think they were actually created to imitate imperative style in a sense. So to say that it only sticks to "using type-theory derived terms" to attract "functional programming hipsters" is probably a bit overstated. Still I think your explanation is quite plausible.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is 'Jargon'. Given the Haskell is regarded as the 'holy grail' of functional languages (at least compared to Scala at any rate), it often feels like the barrier to entry for the average OO developer is pretty massive.

Comment: If `return` is meant to imitate imperative languages, it's a singularly bad imitation.